# remove class only one time when add class many times

Tags: javascript

I have a following code:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
   toast.classList.add('showToast')
   setTimeout(function() {
      toast.classList.remove('showToast')
   }, 3100)
}
```

Assume at 0s I click a lot of times on button, so maybe at 3.1s I receive a lot of remove handle on toast, this is not what I expect because maybe at 3.2s I click on button one more time toast disappear immediately instead action in 3.1s. I want users could click on button as many time they want, equivalent to `addClass()` be handled a lot of time but `removeClass()` only be handled one time corresponding to the last `addClass()` and the last clicking. How can I do that, or maybe could you give me another way to handle this, thanks

Comment: Just put an if statement in. if(!toast.classList.includes('showToast')

Comment: Oh, A simple way, but I guess you test me, I mean `classList.contains()` :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to cancel any still-active timeout when the button is clicked again. In that case, you need to store the timer ID in a variable outside the function, and then call clearTimeout on that before setting the new timeout.

```
let timerId;
btn.onclick = function() {
   toast.classList.add('showToast')
   clearTimeout(timerId);
   timerId = setTimeout(function() {
      toast.classList.remove('showToast')
   }, 3100)
}
```

Note that as shown above `timerId` is a global variable, but this is not ideal. Ideally this code is inside some function which would mean `timerId` does not pollute the global scope. But that depends on information about how your code is architected that you do not show us.

Comment: Very careful, thanks for your caring about also tiny thing

Answer (score 0):

create counter using setInterval()

```
var counterHandle;
var counter = 0;
btn.onclick = function() {
    counter = 0;
    clearInterval(counterHandle);
   toast.classList.add('showToast');
   counterHandle = setInterval(()=>{
                        counter +=1;
                        console.log(counter);
                        if(counter === 3){
                            toast.classList.remove('showToast');
                            clearInterval(counterHandle);
                        }
                        }, 1000);
   
}
```

when the button is pressed many times the counter will always be 0 and when the counter has a value of 3 the command will be executed